# Why can't I get my blackboard bold C to work?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, blackboard

I just downloaded MiKTeX today and `\mathbb{C}` won't work nor will `\C`. Can somebody explain what I need to do/or download? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need the `bbm` package (for example), but as far as I know, `\C` will not work anyway. `\mathbbm{C}` however does!

Comment: With `\usepackage{amssymb}`, you have `\mathbb`.

Comment: I have noticed `\C already defined` Error while trying to redefine `\C` in a document, and that was because `hyperref` with `unicode` option.

Answer (score 7):

You need to load a package such as **amsfonts** or **amssymb** which provide the additional maths alphabet required. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \mathbb{C}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image: blackboard C]

Answer (score 2):

Here's `bbm` - package version -- if this is not nice enough choose `amssymb` (which is apparently preferred by some fellows here;-) )

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}

$\mathbbm{C}$

Will not work: \verb+\C+

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\mathbb` with `amssymb`? `amsfonts` suffices, though.

Comment: While I can't say I like `\mathbb`, I surely dislike `\bbm`. Consider also that the font is only bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

I always define the command `\C` to be `\mathbb{C}`. You can too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
Let $z\in\C$. Then $z\cdot\overline{z}\in\R$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Code example]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using one of the Unicode TeX engines, say either `xelatex` or `lualatex`, then this approach might come in handy.

The `unicode-math` package will load the Latin Modern Math font by default, which also has various blackboard bold glyphs.  The can be accessed as usual via `\mathbb`.  Moreover `unicode-math` defines shorthands for all glyphs (which avoids loading huge token lists).  These can be looked up in [`unimath-symbols`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf).  For blackboard bold glyphs these shorthands are `\BbbA` for A and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{C}$ or $\BbbC$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: +1. You may want to state explicitly which LaTeX engines can handle, or cannot handle, this approach.